# Flask - best way to include HTML inside a template, where the HTML is a string variable

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

For this route:

```
@app.route("/<string:c_id>/br")
def br(c_id):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(...)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("USE ...)
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Bank;")
    BR = mycursor.fetchone()
    BR = BR[1]
    mydb.close()
    return render_template('twelve.html',BR=BR,c_id=c_id)
```

`BR` is a string, written in HTML, e.g. `BR = r'<h1>To sort </h1> <i>to be completed</i>'` Which is part of a database. Fetching BR from the database gives: `<h1>To sort </h1> <i>to be completed</i>`

I would like to include this into my template - `twelve.html`

twelve.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}This Page{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
  <style type="text/css">
    .important { color: #336699; }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h2>This Page</h2>

{{ BR }}

{% endblock %}
```

Currently the webpage reads,`<h1>To sort </h1> <i>to be completed</i>`

How do I get it to read the HTML tags, and use them?
So it actually looks something like this:

## To sort

*to be completed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ BR|safe }}
```

This is called a filter. Read more about them [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#filters).